# How to import dstk in python 3.7 using .?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use the `address` package https://pypi.org/project/address/
However, this package is written for python 2.7 versions. 
Since I wanted to use the version compatible for 3.7, I pulled the version from https://github.com/SwoopSearch/pyaddress/pull/10

The error I am getting is 
`ImportError: cannot import name 'dstk' from '__main__'`
since there is an import statement `from . import dstk`
I am not sure how I can resolve this because if i run `pip install dstk` it throws an error saying no compactible version found:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dstk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dstk
```

Any help would be appreciated. Is there an alternative package that I could use instead if dstk ?

Comment: `address` appears to not have been updated in 7 years. I would suggest looking for a different package.

Comment: yes, but there is a PR just 4 days ago and it seems like an amazing resource to use, just a few roadblocks that I am not able to overcome

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install 'dstk' on Python 3.7, but requires a little work.  I don't know if this will make the 'address' module work, but you can try and let us know.

Per the DSTK developer docs (http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#python) you can manually download the dstk module installation files from http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/python_tools.zip

After downloading the python_tools.zip file and unzipping the file:

1. Open a command prompt to the directory containing the unzipped files.
2. Use the Python 2to3 tool (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/2to3.html) to convert the dstk.py file from using Python2 syntax to using Python3 syntax.

   - On Windows, run the following (Replace %Python37Directory% with the location of your Python37 directory):

```
python %Python37Directory%\Tools\scripts\2to3.py -w dstk.py
```

*NOTE: (If you are using another Operating System (Linux, Mac), you will need to look up documentation for using the Python 2to3 tool as the syntax may be different.)*

3. Run the Setup Utility

```
python setup.py install
```

If all goes well, you should have the DSTK module installed.

Hopefully that will help you get the 'address' module installed. If not, as @PMende mentioned you may need to find a different package.